# How to get this matrix

Tags: matrix, octave

I have this matrix:

```
 S.No.  A         B  
 1     5268020   1756  
 2     15106230  5241  
 3     24298744  9591  
 4     23197375  9129
```

I want to get a matrix which will have two columns [X,Y]. X will take values from S.No. and Y will can be either 1 or 0. For example,  for  `1     5268020   1756`  there should be total `5268020 (1,0)` i.e, (X,Y) pairs and 1756 (1,1) pairs.

How can I get this matrix in Octave ??

Comment: Please provide the complete required output and explain how you got it, as it's not clear what you want from the question as it stands

Comment: @PaulR Lets say I have 1 2 2 in my above matrix. Then in the required matrix [X Y], for X==1, we should have four entries. (X,1), (X,1), (X,0),(X,0)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to fill a matrix with repeated entries (x,0) and (x,1), where x=1...4, where repetition is determined by values found in column A and B. Given the values you supplied that's going to be a huge matrix (67,896,086 rows). So, you could try something like this (replace m below, which has less elements for illustrative purpose):

```
m = [1, 2, 1; 
     2, 3, 2; 
     3, 2, 1; 
     4, 2, 2];
res = [];
for k = 1:4
  res = [res ; [k*ones(m(k, 2), 1), zeros(m(k, 2), 1); 
                k*ones(m(k, 3), 1), ones(m(k, 3), 1)]];
endfor
```

which yields

```
res =

   1   0
   1   0
   1   1
   2   0
   2   0
   2   0
   2   1
   2   1
   3   0
   3   0
   3   1
   4   0
   4   0
   4   1
   4   1
```

Out of curiosity, is there any reason not to consider a matrix like

```
1  0  n
1  1  m
2  0  p
2  1  q
...
```

where `n`, `m`, `p`, `q`, are values found in columns A and B. This would probably be easier to handle , no?